# How can i add active class on a href when scrolling to specified section?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create one page website. Now i'm trying to add active class to my `a` when scrolling to specified `section`. For an example, when i scrolling to `#services` my href with url `#service` will became like this

```
<a class="active" href="#services"><img height="22px" width="22px" src="assets/icon/tools.png">  <span> Service </span></a>
```

Here is my html

```
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#home"><img height="22px" width="22px" src="assets/icon/home.png"> <span> Home </span></a>
  <a href="#services"><img height="22px" width="22px" src="assets/icon/tools.png">  <span> Service </span></a>
  <a href="#portofolio"><img height="22px" width="22px" src="assets/icon/profiles.png"> <span> Portofolio </span></a>
  <a href="#about"><img height="22px" width="22px" src="assets/icon/info.png">  <span> About Us </span></a>
  <a href="#contact"> <img height="22px" width="22px" src="assets/icon/customer-service.png"> <span> Contact Us </span></a>
</div> 

    <div class="main">

    <section id="home">  Main </section> 
    <section id="services">  Services </section> 
    <section id="portofolio">  Portofolio </section> 
    <section id="about">  About Us</section> 
    <section id="contact">  Contact Us </section> 

    </div>
```

and here is my js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var before;

      $("a").on('click', function(event) {

        if (this.hash !== "") {
          event.preventDefault();
          var hash = this.hash;
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
          }, 800, function(){
            window.location.hash = hash;
          });
        }
      });

      $("a").click(function(){
            if(before){
                before.removeClass("active");
            }

            $(this).addClass("active");
            before = $(this);
      });

});
```

I already try this way but now i have multiple problems

```
var sections = $('section')
      , nav = $('.sidenav')
      , nav_height = nav.outerHeight();

    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
      var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop();

      sections.each(function() {
        var top = $(this).offset().top - nav_height,
            bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();

        if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
          nav.find('a').removeClass('active');
          sections.removeClass('active');

          $(this).addClass('active');
          nav.find('a[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').addClass('active');
        }
      });
    });
```

first problem but when i going to my first section, my `href` doesn't have `active class`and the second problem is when i'm in any section the link that has linking to the next section is `active`

[image]

Comment: why do you have two click handlers for `a` tag? What's not working in your code, please explain.

Comment: @GurtejSingh for the first handlers is going to section and second one is add the `active` class to my href and remove `active`

Comment: @GurtejSingh please check my question i already update it

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [Scrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/) jQuery plugin

Answer (score 0):

You only need to monitor the scroll height and determine whether the height is equal to the height of the a label, and then add class.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var sideNav = $(".sidenav > a");
    $("body").on('scroll', function (event) {
        var top = $("body").scrollTop();
        sideNav.each(function (index) {
            if (top === $(this).offset().top) {
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $(this).siblings.removeClass("active");
            }
        })
    });

    $("a").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).siblings.removeClass("active");
    });

});
```